# How to calculate total using reduce() (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have data which has `season` and `fielding` array. `fielding` array has 3 parameters `Catches`, `Runouts`, `Stumpings`. I want to calculate total `Catches`, `Stumpings`, `Runouts`.

```
var data = [
    {
    season:2015,
    fielding:{Catches:2, Runouts:1, Stumpings:1
    },
    {
    season:2016,
    fielding:{Catches:0, Runouts:1, Stumpings:1
    },
    {
    season:2016,
    fielding:{Catches:0, Runouts:0, Stumpings:0
    },
    {
    season:2017,
    fielding:{Catches:1, Runouts:3, Stumpings:1
    },
    {
    season:2017,
    fielding:{Catches:2, Runouts:1, Stumpings:2
    }
]
```

I want final output as object as follows:

```
Catches -> 2+0+0+1+2 = 5
Runouts -> 1+1+0+3+1 = 6
Stumpings -> 1+1+0+1+2 =5
```

What I tried :

```
let dismissals = data.reduce( (a,{season, fielding})  => {

            if(!a[fielding.Catches]){
                a[fielding.Catches] = {};
            }else if(a[fielding.Runouts]){
                a[fielding.Runouts] = {};
            }else if(a[fielding.Stumpings]){
                a[fielding.Stumpings] = {};
            }else{
                a[fielding.Stumpings] += 1;
                a[fielding.Runouts] += 1;
                a[fielding.Catches] += 1;
            }

            return a;
        }, {});
```

My code does not calculate required output and gives `NaN`.

Comment: Why are you initialising something you want to be a number to an empty object?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh ok I will keep that in mind next time I wanted to create object

Comment: What he meant is that ` a[fielding.Catches] = {};` should be ` a[fielding.Catches] = 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the *entries* of `fielding`, and add the value to the [key] in the accumulator (defaulting to `0` if the key doesn't exist yet):

```js
var data=[{season:2015,fielding:{Catches:2,Runouts:1,Stumpings:1}},{season:2016,fielding:{Catches:0,Runouts:1,Stumpings:1}},{season:2016,fielding:{Catches:0,Runouts:0,Stumpings:0}},{season:2017,fielding:{Catches:1,Runouts:3,Stumpings:1}},{season:2017,fielding:{Catches:2,Runouts:1,Stumpings:2}}];

console.log(
  data.reduce((a, { fielding }) => {
    Object.entries(fielding).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      if (key !== '_id') a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val;
    });
    return a;
  }, {})
);
```

Comment: So each parameter inside fielding becomes a `key` and `val` just keeps on adding for that particular key value am I right ?

Comment: Well, `fielding` is an object with properties (keys) and values, not a function - it doesn't have parameters.

Comment: Oh ok sorry for using wrong terminology but got your point :)

Comment: Actually my data is stored in mongoDB so when using `forEach()` it also logs `_id` in console any idea how can I skip that.

Comment: can I replace forEach by something which will give same output.

Comment: Just add `if (key !== '_id')`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Just for your personal reference as you're answering those kind of questions a lot, too :-); using Object.keys() seems to be much more performant https://jsperf.com/hkfdskasnfkanlkasdjflkjl/1 - got my upvote though..

Answer (score 2):

You could use reduce and loop `fielding`'s Object.keys

```js
const res = data.reduce((a, {fielding}) =>
    Object.keys(fielding).forEach(f => a[f] = (a[f] || 0) + fielding[f]) || a
, Object.create(null));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
var data = [
    {
        season:2015,
        fielding:{Catches:2, Runouts:1, Stumpings:1}
    },
    {
        season:2016,
        fielding:{Catches:0, Runouts:1, Stumpings:1}
    },
    {
        season:2016,
        fielding:{Catches:0, Runouts:0, Stumpings:0}
    },
    {
        season:2017,
        fielding:{Catches:1, Runouts:3, Stumpings:1}
    },
    {
        season:2017,
        fielding:{Catches:2, Runouts:1, Stumpings:2}
    }
];

</script>
```